# --enable-languages unrecognized option for configure

Tags: gcc, golang

I am trying to do a build of gcc11 (on RHEL 7.6 which comes with 4.8.5 and no root access).  When I run the following:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/gnu --enable-languages=c,c++
```

I get the response

> configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-languages

When I go to make, it runs through all the languages and ultimately fails on the go portion (which I would love to turn off).  Something about not supporting -fsplit-stack.

So the way I am trying to solve this error in the libgo portion is to edit the enable-languages which I cannot do.  Why is this unrecognized and is there anything I can do downstream to convince it not to try to build the full list of languages?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the help so far I continue to explore what I have read.  A couple of extra pieces of information I neglected to say:

1. I am trying to do as explained on [GNU Source Release Collection](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsrc/)
2. The whole goal of this is to be >= 5.  I don't need 11, I just need one that will build an executable correctly.  Compared with 7,8,9 and 10 I seemed to get closer to the end with 11.  I need >=5 for a python library I am trying to install.

Comment: Does `./configure --help` indicate that `--enable-languages` is a valid option?

Comment: This is only valid for the root configure script, there are many - maybe you're using the wrong one.

Comment: Configuring gcc-11.x.x 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G4vNwA8U6l4PRUfhDxoHsClTRdxMSjHD/view?usp=sharing ....... `gcc-11` can be compiled with gcc/g++ version 8.x or 9.x , not 4.8.5 ........... "Other extra gcc"  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175706/how-to-install-gcc-4-9-2-on-rhel-7-4/47189915#47189915

Comment: @they and @ArtemS.Tashkinov The closest in help is `--enable-FEATURE[=ARG]`.  This is the root configure file created as specified in GNU Source Release Collection page at https://www.gnu.org/software/gsrc/.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thanks, those links in that other question helped me.  The gcc5 version was in the trash can of someone's Google Drive, so there was the issue of downloading something in a trash can, but I have gcc5.3 on my machine now.  Once I have the rpm, I have the process down for not being root as given at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36651091/how-to-install-packages-in-linux-centos-without-root-user-with-automatic-depen

Comment: `gcc53-c++-5.3.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm` Google changed the link to https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNRm9FVnZYUnhyZzg/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-1N6zQa6Sbl_WycG1O9I7JA ...... *But* : gcc version 5.3 **cannot compile** gcc-11.x.x , item #9 `gcc84-c++-8.4.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm` is the only choice in the collection → https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xgFtsiDi2uiB1B0AcOaSpxVizzET-pJf/view?usp=sharing .... Easy unpack_rpm by @unSpawn https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q3d9QqrRhEThYByPDgWEaoxHnqWFWqfE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @KnudLarsen Yeah, I saw that 5.3.0 did not work for me.  But I am up and running now, thanks!